# Married woman covering hair

Tags: tznius-modesty, hair, women, marriage

Is it strictly necessary for a married woman to keep her hair covered in the following situations? If not, how important is it?

1) When alone in the house

2) When alone (or with husband) in the bedroom

3) When chinuch-age children are present

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70560

Answer (score 6):

Magen Avaraham Orach Chaim 75:2 says that in her own house, a lady does not have to cover her hair, however the Bais Shmuel in Even HaEzer 115:9 and the Bach says she does have to cover her hair. In Igros Moshe Even HoEzer 1:58, HaRav Moshe ZATZAL says that the Bach is talking about in a courtyard; however, inside the home, it is permitted.

As she can uncover it her house, then it would definitely be permitted in the bedroom alone with her husband.

Comment: You say Rav Moshe "says that the Bach is talking about...": does he actually rule that a married woman may uncover her hair in her home, though? (And if so, why don't more chu"l frum women do so (when guests are around)??)

Comment: Well there may be those that disagree with HaRav Moshe's interpertation of the Bach. In addition everyone agrees it is commendable to keep it covered at all times as the Gemara mentions by Kimchis.

Comment: I don't know enough in this matter to say anything definitive, but the B"Sh and Bach (and the gemara) are discussing a chatzer "where the rabim doesn't tread", not a house.  It could be the debate is in a chatzer which is shared with other neighbors.  Even though modern practice is to cover hair in front of no matter who, it may have been acceptable to have one's hair uncovered in front of others in a semi private venue (or not acc. to B"Sh and Bach).  This would be similar (in structure, not reasoning) to not eating in a "shuk", but eating in front of others at a kiddush.

Comment: As far as in one's house, there are those at all points in the spectrum, never to kimchis.  Hopefully, people marry hashkafically compatible partners and agree on the guidelines.  If not, it's good to keep in mind that this is the wife's mitzva and a difficult one at that.

Comment: I had always had the question according to those that are very makpid (al pi the Zohar/Kabbalah/Chassidus/whatever it might be) that a woman should always have her hair covered does this go as far as to even when she is alone with her husband (i.e. during relations.) Al pi halacha we see from Gershon Gold's answer one thing, I'm asking if the hakpada of many al pi what I stated above if it applies also in the case of relations.